# How do I get text out of a database and add it to a URL so it could be passed to another php page

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm working on a photo gallery that will have captions under the images. The captions for the thumbnails will be stored in a MYSQL database. When the user clicks on the thumbnail or its caption, I want the caption to be passed to another PHP page where it will be displayed under a large image. How do I pass the caption text from one PHP page to another so it will be display in plain text under a large image? 
[Image gallery with thumbnails](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6QBx.png)

[phpmyadmin database I'm using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqIX9.png)

This is the code for index.php:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Page Title</title>
</head>
<style>
img {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}


#gallery {
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 10px 10px;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 150px;
}

a:link {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:hover {
    color: hotpink;
}


</style>
<body>

<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","art");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }
$result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from  images");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
   {
       $link = $row['link'];
       $pics = $row['pics']; //image
       $caption = $row['caption'];

       echo "<div id='gallery'>";
       //thumbnail with its caption below it
       echo "<a href=".$link."?caption=".urlencode ($caption)." value='fixed text'><img src=".$pics." width='150' height='150' alt='' /> <br>";
            echo $caption."</a>"; echo "</div>";
       echo $caption."</a>"; echo "</div>";

   }


?>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the code for full_image.php:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link type='text/css' rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'/>
    <title>PHP!</title>
  </head>

  <body>


      <?php

      $name=$_GET["name"]; 
      $logo;


             switch ($name) {  //checking to see what code to run base on the value of  the image
case "facebook":
        $logo= '<img src="images/facebook.png" alt="" width="300" height="x">';
        break;
    case "twitter":
       $logo= '<img src="images/twitter.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="x">';
        break;
    case "instagram":
        $logo= '<img src="images/instagram.jpg" alt="" width="300" height="x">';
        break; 
    default:
         error_reporting(0);
}

      ?>


     <?php

     if (isset($_GET['id'] && is_numeric($_GET['id']))) {
        $id=intval($_GET['id']);

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","art");

        $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from images WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result )) {
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            echo '<div id="large_logo" align="center">';
            echo '<img src="'.$row["pics"].'" alt="" width="300" height="x">';
            echo $row['caption']."<br>";
            echo '<p><a href="index.php">Back to gallery</p>'
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else{
            echo "No Image Found";
        }

    }

      ?>
```

Comment: what is the problem with your code .what not working ?

Comment: this one is not valid $caption=$_GET["$caption"];  remove dolor $caption=$_GET["caption"];

Comment: On my index.php page,the words "join Facebook to daytwitter is greal for all peopleinstagram Good for photos" is appearing on the top right side of thumbnail images in plain text.

When I click on the thumbnail images, I get this error message:

Notice: Undefined variable: caption in C:\xampp\htdocs\art\full_image.php on line 14

Notice: Undefined index: in C:\xampp\htdocs\art\full_image.php on line 14

Comment: problem is here $caption=$_GET["$caption"];      remove dolor symbol in caption work like this $caption=$_GET["caption"];

Comment: I removed dollar sign from caption inside the get array but I'm still getting the same error message. Error message: Notice: Undefined index: caption in C:\xampp\htdocs\art\full_image.php on line 14

Comment: in your url there is any query parameter showing like localhost/art/full_image?caption=XXXXX like this ?

Comment: I am passing the names facebook, twitter, and instagram so they can be used in a php switch statement. In my mysql database, I have my 3 logo images stored like this:


full_image.php?name=facebook, 


full_image.php?name=twitter,

full_image.php?name=instagram

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        /*
    on index.php file use id of your image table 
*/

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) 
   {

       echo "<div id='gallery'>";
       //thumbnail with its caption below it
       echo "<a href='full_image.php?id=".$row['id']."' value='fixed text'><img src=".$row['pics'];." width='150' height='150' alt='' /> <br>";
            echo $row['caption']."</a>"; echo "</div>";
       echo $row['caption']."</a>"; echo "</div>";

   }


/*
        on full_image.php file change your code to look like this 
 */

    if (isset($_GET['id'] && is_numeric($_GET['id']))) {
        $id=intval($_GET['id']);

        $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","art");

        $result=mysqli_query($con,"select * from images WHERE id=$id");
        if (mysqli_num_rows($result )) {
            $row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            echo '<div id="large_logo" align="center">';
            echo '<img src="'.$row["pics"].'" alt="" width="300" height="x">';
            echo $row['caption']."<br>";
            echo '<p><a href="index.php">Back to gallery</p>'
            echo '</div>';
        }
        else{
            echo "No Image Found";
        }

    }


        Never use code you used above like that if you are using database to store images then use it id to fetch its information from database rather then hard coding its details
```

Comment: or if u want to use your code then just replace this line in your index.php file
echo "<a href='".$link."?caption=".urlencode ($caption)."' value='fixed text'><img src=".$pics." width='150' height='150' alt='' /> <br>";
            echo $caption."</a>"; echo "</div>";

Comment: I have made some new changes to the full_image.php code above, but Unfortunately, I'm geting an error message when I click on a thumbnai image and go to the full_image.php page. The error is on line 36 where the php if isset statement start.  The following is the error message I am getting:


Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_BOOLEAN_AND, expecting ',' or ')' in C:\xampp\htdocs\art\full_image.php on line 36

Comment: replace line 36 with this line 
if (isset($_GET['id']) && is_numeric($_GET['id'])) {
you are getting error because there is a mistake in bracket closing of isset() function